# Presto: cast an integer array to string?

Tags: sql, arrays, concatenation, presto, trino

I have the following table:

```
my_id, my_array
 1   , [5, 6, 3]
 2   , [1, 5]
 3.  , [6, 7, 5]
```

Would it be possible to do a cast such that the output table would be something like:

```
my_id, my_str
 1   , "5,6,3"
 2   , "1,5"
 3.  , "6,7,5"
```

Or if there is any way I could directly group by my_array would be fine too. Thanks!

Comment: If you find it useful, please add your vote in https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/6347

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_join](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) function

```
select array_join(my_array,',') my_str
```

And of course you can group by array. This works:

```
select max(id) id , my_array
from
(select 1 id, array[5, 6, 3] as my_array) s
group by my_array
```